# Stop auto tab switching in javascript on click

Tags: javascript, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I found this article helpful for what I was needing to do, which was have a slideshow of sorts with a tab and tab_container using JavaScript.  The code works great:

[Automatic tab switch in javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980595/automatic-tab-switch-in-javascript-or-jquery)

However, what I want it to do is if you let the page run, it keeps rotating between the tabs.  But if a tab is manually clicked on (example, they want to read the content on that tab) it stops the auto-rotation of the tabs for the duration of while they are on that webpage.  If the page is refreshed, or they go back to the page, it starts the tab rotation again.

I'm not sure the Javascript code that I can add to the above example to make the auto-rotation stop.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearInterval` to stop the `setInterval` function from running.  `setInterval` returns an ID and you can pass that ID to `clearInterval` to stop it, e.g.

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    ....
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

So just make the code

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    ....

tabs.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    $(this).trigger('slides.swap');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'd also change the `setInterval` function from triggering a `click` to just straight-up triggering `slides.swap`, so that you know the difference between a triggered `click` and a user's click:

```
$('a:eq('+idx+')').trigger('slides.swap');
```

Here's the updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/ZSPX3/151/) from that question.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I actually used the top code from my link in my question.  But the clear interval does give me some ideas I can try.  I'll see if I can get that working using your sugession above.

Thanks again.

Comment: This is the code I used:

$(function() {
    var tabs = $('ul.tabs li');
    tabs.click(function() { $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active'); });
    setInterval(function() {
        var onTab = tabs.filter('.active');
        var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length-1 ? onTab.next() : tabs.first();
        nextTab.click();
    }, 3000);
});